# How to detect delay in touch event? - ANDROID - Eclipse

Tags: android, delay, detection

I have no idea how to do this. How can I detect the delay in a touch event? So I can change a picture to another picture?
I know how to change the picture to another picture, but the delay detection part is what I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

private long lastClickTime = 0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long delay = (lastClickTime==0)?0:currentTime-lastClickTime;
                    //Check delay here and do what you want
                    lastClickTime = currentTime;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```